# On clicking a span, remove all classes from the other spans under the same parent

Tags: jquery, html

There have been a few questions that are similar but are either too broad or don't show good example code.

All I want to do is if a user clicks on span `bButton`, then the `selected` class is removed from all of the other spans and replaced with the `notSelected` class.

```
<div id="mainNav">
  <span id="aButton" class="button selected">a</span>
  <span id="bButton" class="button notSelected">b</span>
  <span id="cButton" class="button notSelected">c</span>
</div>
```

What is the jQuery solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: `bButton` only, or a more generic answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove the `notSelected` class from the clicked element.
2. Add the `selected` class to the clicked element.
3. Remove the `selected` class from all siblings.
4. Add the `notSelected` class to all siblings.

```
$('#mainNav > span').click(function() {

       $(this)
        .removeClass('notSelected')
        .addClass('selected')
        .siblings()
         .removeClass('selected')
         .addClass('notSelected');

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/JCxFT/).

As a sidenote, I wouldn't bother with the `notSelected` class.

You could decide on which element is selected by the presence of `selected` or not. If the element does not have the `selected` class, then it is not selected.

Comment: Yea chaining to the max - very win, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().children('span').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('notSelected');
  });
  $(this).removeClass('notSelected').addClass('selected');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/SnnzV/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').live('click',function(){

$(this).removeClass('notSelected');
$(this).addClass('selected');


    $(this).siblings().each(function(){

          $(this).removeClass('Selected');
          $(this).addClass('notSelected');

    });

});
```